# I have two tuple comparison. Almost the same data. Why this error:

Tags: python, tuples

```
print( ('abc', 1, 2) > ('aaa', 777, 'ssst..') )

print( ('abc', 1, 2) > ('abc', 1, 'ssst..') )
```

Result:

```
True

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//frserv-bu.playtika.local/users$/constantinio/Documents/Python_course/Sedinta3/ex.py", line 33, in <module>
    print( ('abc', 1, 2) > ('abc', 1, 'ssst..') )
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2):

The first comparison goes as far as comparing `'abc'` to `'aaa'`, and then it knows what the result is and doesn't have to continue to the other elements.

In the second comparison, the tuples have the same value for the first two elements, so it has to check the third, at which point it tries to compare `2` to `'ssst..'`, which causes the error you saw.

Comment: Actually the comparison is already "short-circuited" at the first comparison between the strings. Strings are lexicographically ordered in Python.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa You're right. I didn't spot that the first element was different as well.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case the comparison between `'abc'` and `'aaa'` already gives a result (`'abc'` is lexicographically "larger" than `'aaa'`), so the remaining comparisons are not performed (the comparison is "short-circuited").

In the second case the comparison is performed up to the last elements, since all previous elements are equal. The comparison between `2` and `'ssst...'` fails with an exception, because the former is of type `int` and the latter of type `str`.

Answer (score 1):

Comparisons of tuples proceed element by element, from the left, until a comparison of non-equal values can be made. That is,

```
(a, b, c) > (x, y, z)
```

is equivalent to (with some redundant parentheses)

```
(a > x) if (a != x) else ((b > y) if (b != y) else (c > z))
```

or in statement form

```
# result = (a, b, c) > (x, y, z)
if a != x:
    result = a > x
elif b != y:
    result = b > y
else:
    result = c > z
```

In your example, the comparisons `a > x` and `b > y` are valid, but `c > z` is not, since only values of the same type can be ordered. Because comparisons are only made if necessary, the error is only raised when `a == x` and `b == y`.